# How to call web API service continuously

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web API service. When I try to call that service, response time taking much time like more than 4 minutes.

I have checked the JSON Data because of the bulk amount it might take a long time to respond. I'm thinking to split the data and run in a loop.

Problems:
 1. When I try to run in a loop it won't take execting processed data.
 2. I had an ArrayList and I need to do split

Question: How can I call the service continuously?

Code:

```
            var objGetData = objDAL.getArrayListData(id);               
            var jsonToSend = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objGetData, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings{
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore                   
            });

            var client = new RestClient("http://...../....");
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_baseUserName, _basePassword);
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.Parameters.Clear();
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", jsonToSend, "application/json", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

            client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {    
                    objDAL.UpdateResponseDetails(response.Content);

                }
                else
                {
                    LogError("........")
                }
            });

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Is the API you are calling your own code? I suggest improving that server-side code. Anything taking 4 minutes probably has room for improvement.

Comment: @Tim thanks. Yes, this service in server side. What I'm calling that service process itself it is taking much time

Comment: If the computation itself takes that much long, you might want to return first with status somthing like 'processing' and might want to hand off to another processor to handle it.

Comment: @swcraft you meant to say again I need to call another service call? then only one time I can call. what about loop until status/flag is null

Comment: @SENA it would be more like handing off to message queue and some sort of independent task handling the task. This leads to another big topic but that seems what you need if task is very long.  https://farazdagi.com/2014/rest-and-long-running-jobs/